# Android Studio - Unfortunately "appName" has stopped

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I'm trying to build a 2-currency converter app (GNConverter) in Android Studio. I've created a button with onClickLister() to either convert a value or display a Toast message. I get the message "Unfortunately GNConverter has stopped" when ran on my phone.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PromptTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nigeria Naira (NGN)."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:hint="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PromptTextView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ghanaian New Cedi (GHS)."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/PromptTextView"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:hint="0"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnConvert"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:text="Convert"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity Class:

```
public class GNConverter extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private EditText text1;
    private EditText text2;
    private Button btnConvert;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gnconverter);

    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    btnConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvert);

    btnConvert.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.btnConvert){
        double a = Double.parseDouble(text1.getText().toString());
        if (a>0){
            double b = a * 0.016694;
            text2.setText(String.valueOf(b));
        }
        else if (a<=0) {
            Toast.makeText(GNConverter.this, "Enter a Value!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can we get the stacktrace? edit: youre likely not entering a valid double in the edittext..  i suggest you filter it first.

Comment: @jvrodrigues i am new to android studio, please how do i get the stacktrace. Also, the app is running, but when the field is empty and i press the button- ***convert***,. it crashes instead of displaying a toast message.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comments I understood what was going on. First thing, though, is getting the stacktrace, if you're using Android Studio you have to press **Alt-6** to open your logcat and read what is going on in your application. Alternatively you can also click the button that says Android on the lower bar and select the tab that says logcat, you will have an easier time debugging.

About your error - You got a null pointer exception. Null pointers happen when the program expects a variable to be set, but isn't. This particular null pointer happens because when you click the button there is no value in the EditText - it's null - then you pass the null value to the method Double.parseDouble(), that expects a Double.

To avoid this you need to check if there is actually something in the edit text before trying to parse it:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.btnConvert){

        if (text1.getText().toString() != null){
            try{
              double a = Double.parseDouble(text1.getText().toString());

               double b = a * 0.016694;
               text2.setText(String.valueOf(b));
            }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){  
                  Toast.makeText(GNConverter.this, "Enter a valid Value!",          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 
        }else if (a<=0) {
            Toast.makeText(GNConverter.this, "Enter a Value!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
}
```

I also added a try/catch to check, in a ugly and raw way, if the value in the EditText is in fact a number, because if you try to parse the words "hello world" you would get a NumberFormatException.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Can you tag it as an answer then, to help other people with the same issue.